# Not all validation checks execute onsubmit.

Tags: javascript, forms, function, onsubmit

Using a form and javascript to validate fields.
Here is the code where I call the validation javascripts, all of which are in seperate documents but file path is specified.

```
    function validation()
    {
        return validateTitle()
            && validatefirstName()
            && validatesecondName()
            && validateAge()
            && validateEmail()
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="subscribeForm" action="welcome.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validation();">
```

The last two, `validateAge` and `validateEmail` does not execute.
Here is the code for each javascript function:

```
function validateEmail()
{
    var x=document.getElementById('emailadd').value;
    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length || x == null)
    {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}

function validateAge()
{
    var b=document.forms["subscribeForm"]["bday"].value;
    if (b==null || b=="" || b < 1 || b > 105)
    {
        alert("Age invalid.");
        return false;
    }
    else if (isNaN(b))
    {
        alert("Please enter a numeric value.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not returning `true` in any function...

Comment: I entered return = true; for both validations and they still dont execute and now neither does validatesecondName();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your functions needs to return a thruty value if the validation passes. However, as soon as one function returns `false` or a falsey value, the validation process will halt. This is because the `&&` operator uses [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Basically, if `validateTitle()` fails, the rest of the functions won't get executed.